# Android Studio - How can I have switches on the left side of the screen, with the right edges of each switch aligned?

Tags: android, xml

I have been trying to align these switches for several days now and I cannot find the answer. I would like to have the switches themselves aligned (so the right edges aligned), but the entire object (text + switch) on the left side of the page.

Here is what I have, I have tried different combinations of gravity, and different layout types etc:

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="right">
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/sw1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="switch1abc"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/sw2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="switch2"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/sw3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="switch3a"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/sw4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="switch4abcdef"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
    </GridLayout>
```

Here is what it looks like

[image]

Also, I'm not quite sure what "viewStart" is either, can someone explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you can only achieve it with using separate views for text and switch.
Try this:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch one text"/>
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Switch two text"/>
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This works great. Can you tell me how the gridlayout decided what goes where in the grid? It seems to be automatic. Does it just split the contents into however many columns there are?

Is there a way to specify which row/column you want a specific object to be in?

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no way to directly set `View` position in `GridLayout`. To understand how `GridLayout` places views imagine one dimensional array casting to two dimensional array. So if you have 5 views, and 2 rows in a grid, you'll get 2 rows by 3 columns. First view will go into [0,0], second into [0,1], 3->[0,2] and 4 will go in [1,0] and so on. Basically it's rows*columns.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The problem was the different switches width

**layout.xml**

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:gravity="right"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/sw1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="switch1abc"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/sw2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="switch2"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/sw3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="switch3a"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/sw4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="switch4abcdef"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you put into your answer, but this isn't what I am looking for. I want the switches to still be on the left of the page, but aligned. The other answer here worked.